# Search for object in NSMutableArray and change value for that object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate, for-in-loop

I have project where user can add some Items to TableView. My data source for this TableView are objects with 2 properties NSString * ***nameOfItem*** and NSNumber * ***numberOfItem***. Is any possibility to check my NSMutableArray if it contain string *@"someString"* as property ***nameOfItem*** and if yes than change ***numberOfItem*** +1 ?

**UPDATE:**

I try to do it with for(...in...) but it works just when i have only one object in my NSMutableArray. If i have more objects there it create one new object and than change value to ++ on old one:

[image]

Here is some code what i tried:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString*nameToCheck = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.ivc.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
for (Items *itemNamed in self.ivc.shoppingList.items) {
     if ([itemNamed.nameOfItem isEqualToString:nameToCheck]) {
         [itemNamed setNumberOfItem:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[itemNamed.numberOfItem integerValue]+1.0]];
} else {
                Items *item = [Items new];
                [item setNameOfItem:name];
                [item setNumberOfItem:@(1)];
                [self.ivc.shoppingList.items insertObject:item atIndex:0];
}
```

I want to create new one only if is not yet in that list.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What result does this code give you?

Comment: @rdelmar, if i have just one object in that shoppingList.items then it change numberOfItem value ++

Comment: What is the structure of shoppingList? It's not clear from your post, why you are iterating through self.ivc.shoppingList.items, as opposed to self.ivc.shoppingList.

Comment: @rdelmar, self.ivc.shoppingList is NSObject with 3 property. one of property is NSMutableArray * items . in that array i have my items. It's like when you have Core-Data model with shoppingList<-->>Items relationship.

Comment: I tried a modified version of your code, and it worked fine for me. I can't see any reason that a loop through an array would work when the array count is 1, but not for any larger number. What happens when you have more than one object? Nothing?

Comment: @rdelmar, if i have more objects it loop for-in for every object, so if i have object with other "nameOfItem" it do "else" = create new one. That is what i want. If i want to add "Apple" and is not in list will be added if is in the list it change value to 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60714/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-mayo323).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know something like this but you can use a NSDictionary instead of NSArray using the name property as a key. And if you don't want to do that, you can sort the array and make a binary search for element.

Comment: @lulian Popescu, sorry i don't want to search for key just for string saved as property nameOfItem in Item object:)

Comment: I think that i discover a little bug in your code (sorry if i'm wrong). When you check if the names are equal you are checking itemNamed.nameOfItem with name, and I think that here should be nameToCheck